# I am seeing 4th character in output after using substr(0,3) on input characters

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with an input, I am validating max length with this function, but in my html whenever I enter more than 3 values, it gets added to the input answer output when it should only display max 3 values, I'm not sure why.

And no, I can not use `maxlength`, because I need to create this dynamically, sometimes my input field has type text, and sometimes it changes to a random number, not always 3.

As you can see on the picture, I typed 333, then input answer was 333, I added another 3 which I do not see in the input field and the answer changed to 3333 which shouldn't happen.

[image]

Example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
input.addEventListener('input', cutText);

function cutText(e) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.substr(0, 3);
      console.log(e.target.value)
    }

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name"/>
<p id="values"></p>
```

Comment: decpk is correct, alternatively, you could do both operations in the same listener. The goal is both steps happening due to the same event - every time. It seems reasonable to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the ordering of the event, You are first updating the value of the `log` element and then setting the value of the input.

If you have input `aaaa` then it will first set the value of the `log` element to `aaaa` and then set the input as `aaa`

If you would place `curText` first and then `updateValue` then It will behave as expected

```
input.addEventListener('input', cutText);
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', cutText);
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function cutText(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.substr(0, 3);
  console.log(e.target.value)
}

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" />
<p id="values"></p>
```

**1)** Alternatively you can add a single listener and call function in it.

```
input.addEventListener( 'input', (e) => {
    cutText(e);
    updateValue(e);
} )
```

**2** You can just do it in a single callback function

```
input.addEventListener( 'input', ( e ) => {
    const value = e.target.value.substr( 0, 3 );
    e.target.value = value;
    log.textContent = value;
} )
```